# Compare items of list with each other in Python

Tags: python, list

Consider a list o emails:

```
['a@amail.com','b@bmail.com','c@cmail.com',...]
```

I want to compare list items with each other. For example emails would be unique.
What is the way for compare items of list with each other in Python?

Comment: Does this mean you want to remove duplicates from that list? Or why/how do you want to compare the elements?

Comment: I have created a textarea for multiple email adresses. I want to create a raise forms.ValidationError if emails are the same. All emails must be different in teaxtarea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to test whether or not there were duplicates in the list, you can use:

```
if len(set(list_o_emails)) == len(list_o_emails):
    # all are different
else:
    # you had a duplicate
    raise forms.ValidationError # from your comment
```

since `set` will eliminate any duplicates for you and comparing the lengths will tell you whether or not any duplicates were removed.

Comment: and using `list(set(list_o_emails))` will effectively remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use for `any()` with a list comprehension:

```
if any([emails.count(email) > 1 for email in emails]):
    raise forms.ValidationError("Emails must be unique.")
```